# ATK4 Autocomplete issue

Tags: php, file, autocomplete, atk4, missing-data

I'm new to ATK4.
I'm trying to implement an Autocomplete field, but I had only an error when I try to define the field.
I'm running all on a MAC with the last version (4.2.4) of ATK4. All other functions (field types) seems to work well, but when I define a field of type autocomplete I get the same error I saw on the example: http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/autocomplete

The case is I defined a model:

```
class Model_Agenda extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='Agenda';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('DATE');
        $this->addField('TIME');
        $this->addField('DRIVERID');
        $this->addField('STUDENTID');
        $this->hasOne('STUDENTID')->display(array('form'=>'autocomplete/Basic'));

    }
}
```

and then on my Page:

```
    $form = $this->add('Form');
    $form->addField('ReadOnly','Date')->Set($_GET['date']);
    $form->addField('ReadOnly','Time')->Set($_GET['time']);
    $form->addField('ReadOnly','Driver')->Set($_GET['driverid']);       
    $client=$form->addField('autocomplete','studentid');
```

something simple, but nothing, I cannot get the autocomplete field, I ever get an error that say that "autocomplete.php" doesn't exist (actually the file doesn't exist and I try to download the github module, but either that module includes this file), anyway the error I get is:

Exception_PathFinder, code: 0

Additional information:

```
file: Form/Field/Autocomplete.php
type: php
attempted_locations:
0: /Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/lib/Form/Field/Autocomplete.php
1: /Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/atk4/lib/Form/Field/Autocomplete.php
2: /Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/atk4-addons/mvc/Form/Field/Autocomplete.php
3: /Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/atk4-addons/misc/lib/Form/Field/Autocomplete.php
class: Form_Field_Autocomplete
namespace:
orig_class: Form_Field_Autocomplete
/Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/atk4/lib/PathFinder.php:207
```

Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about this add-on, right: https://github.com/atk4/autocomplete?

Looks like issue with PathFinder unable to find appropriate location of namespaced addons.
Please post here part of your API_Frontend class where you add additional locations to pathfinder and also tell me something more about your folder structure (in which folder you have put autocomplete add-on files).

ATK 4.2.4 version is not last. Can you try to upgrade ATK to version 4.2.5? It's not officially released, but is available in GitHub master branch here: https://github.com/atk4/atk4?
I hope everything will work with 4.2.5 version but if not, then I'll help you solve this issue.

And one more thing - if you're creating form fields manually, then you need to set Model for that $client field. I guess it can be done with $client->setModel('Agenda');

---

**EDIT: correct answer**

In line

```
$client=$form->addField('autocomplete','studentid');
```

you should write full autocomplete field class name with namespace like this:

```
$client=$form->addField('autocomplete/Basic', 'studentid');
```

One more thing to note is to use lowercase function name. So instead of `Set()` use `set()`.

Comment: DarkSide, first of all tks for your answer.
1) I downloaded the 4.2.5 version (download the ZIP file, and update my ATK4 directory with the new one)
2) Now I have a new error:
Stack trace:
File   Object Name Stack Trace
/Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/page/agenda.php :14   Loggererror_handler(8, "Undefined variable: n", "/Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/page/agenda.php", 14, Array(5))
??????

Regarding the $client-field, yes, I think that I used the correct model with setModel('Agenda'), but anyway I can verify it.

Comment: @Mack How about this "... Looks like issue with PathFinder unable to find appropriate location of namespaced addons. Please post here part of your API_Frontend class where you add additional locations to pathfinder and also tell me something more about your folder structure (in which folder you have put autocomplete add-on files). ..."?

Comment: About undefined variable error I can't tell you anything without seeing your code, but I guess this is not issue with ATK, but with your /page/agenda.php file (row 14).

Comment: OK, regarding the errors (n variable,etc) are solved. I cannot get why with 4.2.4 those errors doesn't come out, and with 4.2.5 they are evidenced but again, are solved. I have again the autocomplete.php issue. I tried to replace the atk4-addons with the autocomplete files. My proyect is all inside a directory called rutas, inside it I have atk4, atk4-addons, doc, lib, logs, pages and template,  copy of one example!. I modified API_Fronted to update the menu, that's all, and of course I updated config.php with my DB. How I add autocomplete using API_Frontend?

Comment: Ok, I think that I got your idea, I added        $this->addLocation('atk4-addons',array(
                    'php'=>array(
                        'mvc',
                        'misc/lib',
                        'autocomplete-master'
                        )
                    ))
            ->setParent($this->pathfinder->base_location); into api_frontend, and I copied autocomplete-master into atk4-addons, but nothing happen, the error is already there

Comment: OH MAN, this was so stupid of me :))) Line `$client=$form->addField('autocomplete','studentid');` should be `->addField('field type', 'field name')` where field type is not "autocomplete", but should be correctly namespaced field class name: `autocomplete\Basic`. Can you try that now? I also edited my answer above.

Comment: @Mack did this work for you? If so, then please accept my answer :)

Comment: DarkSide, sorry about the delay, NOPE, doesn't work, it give me a new error 0: /Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/atk4-addons/autocomplete/lib/Form/Field/Basic.php, any other suggestion?

Comment: Where is your autocomplete addon located? Isn't it in /Library/WebServer/Documents/rutas/atk4-addons/autocomplete/... ? And please post here lines from your Frontend class where you add path to addons like ...->addLocation(...).

Comment: OK!!!!!!, thanks, I had added the directory autocomplete-master and I had added to my frontend autocomplete-master too, and that doesn't work. I just renamed the autocomplete-master for autocomplete and modified my link on frontend. My mistake was I believe that "autocomplete\Basic" refers to "autocomplete" CLASS and not "autocomplete" directory. IT'S WORKING NOW! thanks a lot @DarkSide

Comment: yeah, `autocomplete` is namespace and is treated as directory, `Basic` is name of class and is treated as file name. That's the way ATK works with namespaced classes. You can even have class like `foo\bar\qwerty\MyClass` and that means it'll be located in directory structure `foo/bar/qwerty` and filename `MyClass.php`